# Postgresql database getting slow (selection) for millions records

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

Postgresql database getting slow when trying to fetch data for millions records.  I tried with **Materialized view**, however performance was drastically fast but it doesn't give real time data.

I am also using aggregation ex. sum, count, group by clause etc...

```
SELECT offer_id as off_id,
  COUNT(distinct ip) as hosts,
  COUNT(distinct click_id) as clicks 
FROM offer_affiliate_stats 
WHERE 
  created_dt >= '2019-06-01' 
AND 
  created_dt  <= '2019-06-30' 
GROUP BY off_id;
```

I have tried with **Materialized view**.

Indexes are applied on id, created_dt, click_id

My output should be like this:

```
off_id               | 79
hosts                | 4
clicks               | 4
offer_name           | "Testing Javelin"
offer_id             | 
total_conversions    | 
total_income         | 
optimised_count      | 
optimised_income     | 
approved_income      | 
approved_conversions | 
declined_income      | 
declined_conversions | 
total_payout         |
```

Actually without using **distinct** keyword it work flawlessly but when I use **distinct** it takes long time.

Comment: At a minimum, we'd have to see the definition of offer_affiliate_stats with the associated indexes and the output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) your query.  Please edit your question and add these.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I have edited the question.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should you configure your database?

You see below link: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html

Especially `work_mem` default value is 4MB. You may increase to 100MB.

You change code like:

```
SELECT  offer_id as off_id,
        COUNT(ip) as hosts,
        COUNT(click_id) as clicks 

FROM 
(select distinct offer_id,
        ip ,
        click_id    
        from offer_affiliate_stats 
WHERE created_dt >= '2019-06-01' 
AND created_dt  <= '2019-06-30' ) as t
GROUP BY off_id;
```